# Welcome activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, chronometer

I am making an app in android for which I need a welcome activity. I want to intent my welcome activity automatically after five seconds.Should i use a chronometer for that?

Comment: Use a handler with a delay of 5 seconds. You don't need a chronometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splash screen is not recommended if you must have to use it.

if you are going to any start-up operation you can us splash screen.

Anyway as per your situation

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent startLandingPageActivity = new Intent(MainLauncher.this, LandingPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(startLandingPageActivity);

    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splash scree is a better option for it:

Android splash screen are normally used to show user some kind of progress before the app loads completely. Some people uses splash screen just to show case their app / company logo for a couple of second.

For implementation follow this link:
 http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 0):

Show your WelcomeScreen for few seconds by adding this code to your `WelcomeActivity` after `setContentView` method.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish(); //This closes current activity
            }
        }, 4000); //It means 4 seconds
    }
```